# How do I do temporal correlations of matrices?

Tags: time-series, correlation, clustering, matrix, spatio-temporal

I have a some data like the following explaining the presence of a relation between various entities `(A,B,C,...)` in my system at time `t`:

```
At T=1

   A B C D . . .
A  0 2 1 0 . . .
B  2 0 1 3 . . .
C  2 1 0 2 . . .
D  0 3 2 0 . . .
.  . . . . . . . 

At T=2

   A B C D
A  0 3 1 0 . . .
B  3 0 1 3 . . .
C  2 1 0 2 . . . 
D  0 3 2 0 . . .
.  . . . . . . . 

At T=3
...
```

My goal is to understand how the matrix is changing temporally and characterize it in a meaningful way to be able to extract temporal points where the matrix underwent a significant change (again some meaningful metric) and also figure out the region inside the matrix where this change happened. I am just wondering if there is a standard way of doing this. Any suggestions? I am using Python and NumPy.

Answer (score 1):

It would appear to me that you have 16 observations every time period (T=1,T=2,,,,). Identify and build a parsimmonious Vector Arima Model (VARIMA) http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Autoregressive_moving_average_model to characterize how the 16 endogenous series relate over time. VAR models may be inadequate as they assume that the equations are pure autoregressive rather than a parsimonious mixture of AR and MA structure.

Comment: +1 Thank you for your suggestions. I meant to provide the matrix as an example. In reality, the number of entities I have is much greater in the order of thousands. I updated my question to reflect this but my data is essentially a graph depicting the relations between various entities in my system. A snapshot of this graph is taken at regular time intervals which is what I am trying to understand. Would you still suggest a preliminary examination with VARIMA?

Comment: @Legend Given the magnitude of your problem VARIMA might not be feasible. ARIMA on each of the "relation measures" might yield a quicker result. Some actual data might help this discussion along. You can do this publicly or privately as you wish. I prefer the public approach as we can all learn in this way.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestions. I will try to get back with some data.